# get all the past 7 dates from the current date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, web

How to show all the dates from the past 7 days starting from the current day . For eg : if today is 10/3/2018 . I want the output to be

```html
10/3/2018
9/3/2018
8/3/2018
7/3/2018
6/3/2018
5/3/2018
4/3/2018
```

Now the main thing is that my table does not have entry for all the dates .So if i use between or something like that . it will show me only the dates that are available in the table.

I am actually trying to fetch the data for the past 7 days and if nothing is available for that day then zero or blank should come.

EDIT 1:

```html
Select curdate()
union Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 1 day) 
union Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 2 day) 
union Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 3 day) 
union Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 4 day)
union Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 5 day) 
union Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 6 day)
from detail
```

Now this is returning all the previous dates like i wanted , but i am still not able to `group` it properly with the `where` clause . So that the dates return the number of orders placed on that day and return 0 if nothing is found .

`SELECT count(id) from detail where status in(3,7)`.

This was the original query

Comment: `SELECT count(id) from order_detail where  DATE(date_added) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 7` .I tried this but it's not working

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: You can use Union all

Comment: Always add question details to the question via an edit.  Don't  use comments.

Answer (score 2):

You  **NO need to add any date in any tables**

you can get last seven days using UNION like below

```
Select if(created_at,created_at,0) as past_seven_days from (

    Select curdate() as past_seven_days
          union
    Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 1 day)
          union
    Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 2 day)
          union
    Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 3 day)
          union
    Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 4 day)
          union
    Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 5 day)
         union
    Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 6 day)
         union
    Select date_sub(Curdate(),interval 7 day) )as p

left join url as u on p.past_seven_days = u.created_at
```

[image: Ouput]

Comment: @ Harjeev Singh, If you create a calendar table containing all the dates you needed, then the table size will get increase for every year. because there is leap year too. 
so, this method is easiest way to get the last 7 days...

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a calendar table containing all the dates you need. You can then left join it to your data to get what you are after

Comment: that makes sense .If nothing works out i'll go with that only.